# How to find the JetPack version of NVIDIA Jetson Device?

Tags: nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier, nvidia-jetpack-sdk

Is there a way to find the version of the currently installed JetPack on my NVIDIA Jetson Xavier AGX kit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the JetPack version, architecture and dependencies,

```
sudo apt-cache show nvidia-jetpack

#Package: nvidia-jetpack
#Version: 4.4.1-b50
#Architecture: arm64
#Maintainer: NVIDIA Corporation
#Installed-Size: 194
#Depends: nvidia-cuda (= 4.4.1-b50), nvidia-opencv (= 4.4.1-b50), nvidia-cudnn8 (= 4.4.1-b50)
```

For the version specifically,

```
sudo apt-cache show nvidia-jetpack | grep "Version"

#Version: 4.4.1-b50
```

Comment: On my Jetson this command outputs 4 versions, how to know which one was installed?

Answer (score 4):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/jetsonhacks/jetsonUtilities.git
cd jetsonUtilities
python jetsonInfo.py
```

Output:

```bash
NVIDIA Jetson Nano (Developer Kit Version)
 L4T 32.5.1 [ JetPack 4.5.1 ]
   Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
   Kernel Version: 4.9.201-tegra
 CUDA 10.2.89
   CUDA Architecture: 5.3
 OpenCV version: 3.4.17-dev
   OpenCV Cuda: YES
 CUDNN: 8.0.0.180
 TensorRT: 7.1.3.0
 Vision Works: 1.6.0.501
 VPI: ii libnvvpi1 1.0.15 arm64 NVIDIA Vision Programming Interface library
 Vulcan: 1.2.70
```

Comment: notice that the OpenCV version and OpenCV Cuda are python environment dependent. so if you are using venv or conda, make sure to activate the environment and then invoke jetsonInfo.py